# Как правильно сделать Push на GitHub?

Tags: git, github

В Git я новичок. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно делать Push на сервер GitHub.

На ПК1 был создан проект и залит в репозиторий на GitHub. Спустя некоторое время последняя версия проекта была скачана на ПК2 с Github (просто как архив) и доработана.

Вопрос: как правильно отправить эти изменения из локального репозитория ПК2 в репозиторий на GitHub, чтобы полностью перезаписались файлы на сервере и удалились, те которые были удалены в новой версии на ПК2?

P.S. попытался сделать push, но он не проходит, выдает ошибку:

```
git.exe push --progress "origin" master

To https://github.com/zepelinjam/GeoQuiz
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/zepelinjam  /GeoQuiz'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (4625 ms @ 28.06.2017 23:38:37)
```

Так понял, что нужно сначала сделать pull старой версии с удаленного репозитория, но ведь тогда код сливается?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

отправляются не *файлы*, а *история* их изменений.

> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>   hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
>   hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

сообщение означает, что в вашем локальном хранилище (репозитории) и в удалённом «история пошла разными путями». и вам предлагается предварительно выполнить команду `pull` для того, чтобы скачать из удалённого хранилища тамошнюю версию истории и (здесь у вас локально) объединить её с вашей локальной историей, а уж только после этого выполнять команду `push`.

это обычная процедура работы с хранилищами.

но, **насколько я понял**, тамошняя история вас вообще не интересует, и с этим удалённым хранилищем кроме вас никто не работает. в таком случае вы можете перезаписать тамошнюю историю своей версией. для этого надо добавить опцию `-f` (`--force`) к команде `push`:

```
$ git push -f остальные-опции-и-параметры
```

Comment: `тамошнюю` - это что-то новенькое