# Проблема с git push

Tags: git

Делаю

```
D:\work\project>git push -f http://49-git.loc/dosd/MPZ master
Username for 'http://49-git.loc': admin
Password for 'http://user@49-git.loc':
warning: redirecting to http://49-git.loc/dosd/MPZ.git/
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 7.07 KiB | 2.36 MiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch on
this project.
To http://49-git.loc/dosd/MPPZ
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://49-git.loc/dosd/MPZ'
```

Ловлю ошибку. Без force ловлю такое как тут [Как правильно сделать Push на GitHub?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685010/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-push-%d0%bd%d0%b0-github)

Как запушить? На сайт локального гита пускает, вроде не помню там запретов.

Comment: Какой локальный сервер у вас? Если гитлаб, то надо обладать правом "Master" для того чтобы пушить в мастер. Пользователь "Developer" может создавать свои ветки, пушить в них и создавать pull request'ы

Comment: зачем вам `push -f` ? из-за этого `-f` (force режим) и не даёт залить на защищенную ветку.

Comment: Так посмотрите по своей же ссылке решение есть, в чем проблема?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev так решение по ссылке в том, что б включить режим force. Я включил - и получаю новую ошибку.

Comment: решение там в git pull для начала. если не поможет, то ресетится зарание закинув изменения в stash

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev я понял в чём ошибка. pull не помагает, я задал новый вопрос, как записать файл в конкретную папку... Посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/886067/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0?noredirect=1#comment1444272_886067 вот это и привело к ошибке.