# Как отправить один файл в определенную "папку" гита?

Tags: git

Есть локальный репозиторий. Мне нужно файл в текущей папке **обновить** на гите (не путать с добавить). Какой комбинацией это можно сделать? Например, файл myprog.cs находится в проекте А, в "папке" B (виртуальная папка на гите). Т.е. `http://rep.loc/department/A/tree/master/B/myprog.cs` нужно обновить файл B. В "папке" А есть ещё несколько "папок" (которые касаются других частей проекта). Можно ли заставить гит работать не со всем проектом, а только с веткой B, как указать что файлы связаны с веткой В, а не с корнем?

Я пробовал делать

```
git add myprog.cs
git commit -m new_update
git push http://rep.loc/department/A master
```

Последняя строчка дает ошибки по которым становится понятно что файл гит пытается записать "не туда". Как мне указать, что надо в ветку B записать?

```
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected >branch on
this project.
To `http://rep.loc/department/A`
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to `http://rep.loc/department/A`
```

Пояснения rep.loc - имя локального репозитория. department - группа с проектами. А - имя проекта. master - ветка мастера. B - папка в проекте А. Скорее всего нужно вначале правильно pull или clone сделать, чтоб гит знал, что он пушит... мне не понятно как это сделать для одного файла.

Пробовал так:

```
>git clone http://rep.loc/department/A
Cloning into 'A'...
Username for '....': username
Password for '....':
warning: redirecting to http://rep.loc/department/A.git/
remote: Enumerating objects: 59, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (59/59), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (44/44), done.
remote: Total 59 (delta 30), reused 25 (delta 11)
Unpacking objects: 100% (59/59), done.

>copy myprog.cs A\B\
Скопировано файлов:         1.

>git add A\B\myprog.cs
>git commit -m mycomment
[master (root-commit) 805039f] mycomment
1 file changed, 676 insertions(+)
create mode 100644 A/B/myprog.cs

>git push -f http://rep.loc/department/A master
Username for 'http://rep.loc': 
Password for 
warning: redirecting to http://rep.loc/department/A.git/
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 7.10 KiB | 1.78 MiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch
this project.
To http://rep.loc/department/A
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://rep.loc/department/A'
```

Или такое (если без force, force соеветуют в некоторых случаях)

```
>git push http://rep.loc/department/A master 
....
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://rep.loc/department/A'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Делаю `git pull http://rep.loc/department/A master`

> fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

как правильно всё-таки "обновить" файл что б без диалога?

Comment: Отправлять не выйдет. Поэтому: 1) Помещаете ваш файл в нужную папку 2) Коммитите файл 3) Пушите в удаленный репозиторий

Comment: @gil9red 1) удалил .git  2) Делаю clone - получаю A\B\myprog.cs. 3) делаю copy. 4) делаю add  A\B\myprog.cs - success. 5) делаю commit - success. 6) делаю push - ошибка(

Comment: 1) зачем удалять? Да и ошибка ведь написана: `remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch`

Comment: Удалять... что б с "чистого листа". Т.е. всё вычистил всё и закачиваю "чистый проэкт" что б легко было повторить. И что нужно сделать что б заработало?( Я галочек на доступ вроде нигде не видел

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246503/how-to-fix-you-are-not-allowed-to-push-code-to-protected-branches-on-this-proje

Comment: push --force прошел... но это не правильно. Локальный репозиторий стал... чистым :( с одним файлом (как хорошо что копии есть).  А как обновить так, что б затронуло один файл, а не все поудаляло...?

Comment: в каталоге `b` у вас, вероятно, подмодуль находится?

Comment: ну так [с ним и работайте](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8).

Comment: Я не пойму, почему пропали файлы... залитые через web. Файлы залитые через git-консоль из-за force не пропадают.

Comment: Может так: `git fetch ;
git checkout origin/master -- path/to/file`. или пробывать ваш порядок действий но с флагом `git commit -m 'my test' --amend`

Comment: Думаю информации с комментариев хватит что б решить эту задачу... я ещё потестирую свои решения... и... опубликую их, если ответа не будет. Модули ещё не пробовал. Статья модули конечно "весёлая" (ввиду проблем которые в ней описаны))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем я пользуюсь скрипотами так...

Создал папку. Папка с главным проэкотом допустим MyProject

```
git add MyProject
git commit -m название_коммита_какое-то
git push -u origin
```

Если какая то из команд сбоит - применяю --force

Если надо слить один единственный файл - применяю git add путь_и_файл, потом commit и push.

Не помню как настроил папку с проэктом. Само проще сделать git clone, и гит сам создат нужные папки (если проэкт уже на гите). Создать чистый проэкт можно через сайт развернутого гита.

Надеюсь начинающим это поможет.
Если есть идеи по лучше - создайте ответ - с удовольствием приму.

Ещё помогло это
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246503/fix-gitlab-error-you-are-not-allowed-to-push-code-to-protected-branches-on-thi

Comment: скрипоты – это такие большие неуклюжие скрипты?