# Как залить изменения на свою ветку в удаленный репозиторий на гитхаб?

Tags: git, gitlab

Помоги разобраться, пишет:

To https://github.com/project.git
! [rejected]        sorvard -> sorvard (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Может кто поделится пошаговой инструкцией, что я делаю не так???

Comment: У вас локальная ветка позади ветки удаленной. Попробуйте `git pull -r`

Comment: Не помогло, к сожалению ...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно сделать Push на GitHub?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685010/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-push-%d0%bd%d0%b0-github)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте force push - но только если уверены, что с вашей веткой более никто не работает кроме вас.

```
  git push -f origin HEAD:<your branch>
```

Чтобы такое не повторялось впредь, вам, да, следует почаще затаскивать изменения в свою ветку, - так, как вам подсказали, -
`git pull --rebase origin <your branch>`

Либо создайте в репозитории новую ветку и перенесите ваш коммит с помощью
`git cherry-pick <uuid>`, после чего сделайте commit и push.

Comment: Спасибо большое) Помогло!